# What are the differences between the nouns, "shoot" and "shot"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns, compounds

I am confused about the difference between *photo shoot* and *photo shot*.

Here are a few examples of what I mean:

1. In a publishing house, the director talking to an assistant:

   > We have a **photo shoot**.
2. An app name:

   > Instant **photo shot**
3. > Alice met a guy on Tinder last week who showed her a **boob shot** of a girl his roommate hooked up with, and it was her very own boob.
4. > A: I'm gonna steal your cell phone for a second.
   >
   > B: Wait a minute. Why?
   >
   > A: Just relax, scaredy-cat.
   >
   > B: What are you doing?
   >
   > A: I'm taking a picture of my junk. No. I'm adding myself to your calendar right here, next Thursday.
   >
   > B: Are you asking me on a date? Is that a yes?
   >
   > A: I don't know. Let me see that **junk shot** first.

Comment: I wonder if the high number of views is not due, in part, to people searching for "boob shot" and "junk shot".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**shoot** & **shot** are film/movie & professional photographic terms.

**shoot** describes the 'event' at which film stock is used to make the movie/photographs.

The shoot is a general term for the entire occasion, at which there may be several hundred people, all doing different tasks that make up the event; from catering, locations & logistics, transport, carpenters & riggers, lighting specialists, sound recordists, cameramen & grips [camera movers], production crew, actors, director … all are on the same 'shoot'.

Stills & movie would be differentiated as
photo shoot / stills shoot or
film shoot / movie shoot.
'stills' is the movie term for non-moving pictures.
A stills photographer would call them shots or photographs, as there is no 'moving' alternative to cause confusion.

A **shot** is either

- The specific way the camera is lined up &/or moved, re-focussed etc., to point at the actors or scene, in order to film that one small section of the action, or
- for stills photography, either the above, or simply any one single photograph - whether it required an entire film crew to take it or not.

An aside… this is where we get the term "Who is calling the shots?"
The answer is - the Director.

Comment: @snailboat - thanks. It's an industry I work in, so it felt fairly natural to set it out that way to me. I'm no good at the actual grammar ones ;)

Comment: @ snailboat / Tetsujin - I'm sorry. I just edited my question. Hopefully, it provides more detail for you in order to help me to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: Apparrently the film industry is _not_ the origin of the idiom.  See  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113815/whats-the-origin-of-the-figure-of-speech-call-the-shots